# Continuously deploy two branches to two separate openshift applications on Travis CI?

Tags: git, openshift, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

I have a git repo that has many developing branches, plus a branch called **production** for production, and **master** is used for staging.

What I'm trying to achieve is that whenever someone pushes to master, the application is built then deployed to a staging app, and when someone pushes to the production branch, the application is built then deployed a different production app.

I configured my `.travis.yml` file like so:

```
sudo: false
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '0.10'
env:
  global:
  - GH_REF: github.com/AFusco/MyRepo.git
  - secure: (hidden)
install: "./scripts/install_dependencies.sh"
cache:
   directories:
    - node_modules
    - bower_components

deploy:
  provider: openshift
  skip_cleanup: true
  user: myname@gmail.com
  password:
    secure: (hidden)
  domain: correct_openshift_namespace
  app:
    master: staging
    production: production
after_success: 
  - ./scripts/deploy_app.sh
```

Whereas, in my `./script/deploy_app.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ev

rm -rf ./dist
grunt build
cd ./dist
git init
git status
git config --global push.default simple
git config --global user.email "travis@travis-ci.com"
git config --global user.name "Travis CI"
git checkout -b master
git add --all
git commit -am "Travis deploy"
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://45d0ca6189f5cfc35100010c@staging-mynamespace.rhcloud.com/~/git/staging.git/'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this, and I quite feel like a noob.

Since I committed all the files inside the `deploy_app.sh` script, I didn't change directory after the script finished so the `dpl` script was being launched inside the root directory and not inside `./dist`

I had to change my `.travis.yml` file to:

```
sudo: false
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '0.10'
env:
  global:
  - GH_REF: github.com/AFusco/MyRepo.git
  - secure: (hidden)
install: "./scripts/install_dependencies.sh"
cache:
   directories:
    - node_modules
    - bower_components

deploy:
  provider: openshift
  skip_cleanup: true
  user: myname@gmail.com
  password:
    secure: (hidden)
  domain: correct_openshift_namespace
  app:
    master: staging
    production: production
after_success: 
  - ./scripts/deploy_app.sh
  - cd ./dist
```